# magento programmatically add more custom options

Tags: magento

I would like programmatically create product with more then one custom option. My current code is bellow but only last option is saved. Can anyone help?

```
$options = array(
        array(
            'is_delete' => 0,
            'title' => 'First Line',
            'type' => 'text',
            'is_require' => 0,
            'sort_order' => 1,
        ),
        array(
            'is_delete' => 0,
            'title' => 'Second Line',
            'type' => 'text',
            'is_require' => 0,
            'sort_order' => 2,
        )  
);

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
$optionInstance = $product->getOptionInstance();

foreach($options as $option){

    $product->setHasOptions(1);

    if (isset($option['is_require']) && ($option['is_require'] == 1)) {
        $product->setRequiredOptions(1);
    }

    $optionInstance->addOption($option);
    $optionInstance->setProduct($product);
    $product->save();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok my solution is below:

```
$options = array(
        array(
            'title' => 'First Line',
            'type' => 'field',
            'is_require' => 0,
            'sort_order' => 1,
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'Second Line',
            'type' => 'field',
            'is_require' => 0,
            'sort_order' => 2,
        )
);

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);

$product->setHasOptions(true)->save();

foreach($options as $option_data){
    $option = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option')
        ->setProductId($product->getId())
        ->setStoreId($product->getStoreId())
        ->addData($option_data);

    $value = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option_value');
    $value->setOption($option);
    $option->addValue($value);

    $option->save();
    $product->addOption($option);
    $product->save();
}
```

Comment: Could you please help on this question for add product option value.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/292966/magento-2-add-product-option-custom-value-in-product-rest-api

Answer (score 2):

Here the code is below:

```
$selectOptionId = 1379;
$selectOptionValueId = 794;
$textOptionId = 1380;
$fileOptionId = 1381;
// Update custom option of Text Field type
$customTextFieldOption = array(
    "title" => "Custom Text Field Option Title Updated",
    "type" => "field",
    "is_require" => 1,
    "sort_order" => 20,
    "additional_fields" => array(
        array(
            "price" => 13.00,
            "price_type" => "fixed",
            "sku" => "custom_text_option_sku_updated",
            "max_characters" => 127
        )
    )
);
Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option_api')->update($textOptionId, $customTextFieldOption, $store = null);
```

// Update custom option of Dropdown type

```
$customDropdownOption = array(
    "title" => "Custom Dropdown Option Title Updated to Multiselect",
    "type" => "multiple",
    "additional_fields" => array(
        array(
            "value_id" => $selectOptionValueId,
            "price" => 14.00,
            "price_type" => 'percent',
            "sku" => "custom_select_option_sku_1 updated",
            "sort_order" => 26
        )
    )
);
Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option_api')->update($selectOptionId, $customDropdownOption, $store = null);
```

Let me khow ,if it is not working

Answer (score 0):

In the following example code, I am adding custom option with title ‘**Size**’ and I have added two values to it ‘**Long**’ and ‘**Short**’.

```
$productId = YOUR_PRODUCT_ID;
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

$options = array(
                'title' => 'Size',
                'type' => 'drop_down',
                'is_required' => 1,
                'sort_order' => 0,
                'values' => array(
                                array(
                                    'title' => 'Long',
                                    'price' => 10.50,
                                    'price_type' => 'fixed',
                                    'sku' => '',
                                    'sort_order' => 0,
                                ),
                                array(
                                    'title' => 'Short',
                                    'price' => 0,
                                    'price_type' => 'percent',
                                    'sku' => 'test-product-sku',
                                    'sort_order' => 0,
                                )
                            )
            );

$product->setProductOptions(array($options));
$product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
$product->save();
```

After that it will look like:-
[image]